# Exclude records matching subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

There is probably an obvious answer to this question, but I am having one heck of a time getting anywhere with it.

Consider the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM reports AS r
JOIN reportvalues AS rv ON rv.report_id = r.report_id
JOIN metrics AS m ON m.metric_id = rv.metric_id
WHERE r.report_id NOT IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT report_id
    FROM exclude_report
)
```

In this query, `exclude_report` is a view constructed in a similar manner.

Now what happens is the query takes an EXTREMELY long time to execute, presumably because the subquery is being executed over each and every row in the parent query. However, I am finding no feasible means of doing this any other way.

Oh great SQL wizards, please advise. I really need a way of doing this all in SQL, which I will be using in SSRS.

Comment: There is not enough info here. Just run the query in SQL server management studio and look execution plan. It will show you what aspects are slow and then you can optimise the query based the results. Always optimise with facts not conjecture.

Comment: Considering I'm a MySQL guy, the output of the execution plan isn't really helping me much. Each query individually will run in a matter of seconds, but the entire thing left running for 5 minutes never completed.

The stage where the execution plan shows the highest cost is a "Clustered Index Scan" over all the PK's, followed by a "Hash Match". I feel lost and confused.

Comment: BTW, do you really need the SELECT * ? Or would less columns be applicable?

Comment: I really need all the fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distinct is probably killing you, you don't need distinct in a subquery when using in

Is this better?

```
SELECT *
FROM reports AS r
JOIN reportvalues AS rv ON rv.report_id = r.report_id
JOIN metrics AS m ON m.metric_id = rv.metric_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM exclude_report e 
        WHERE e.report_id = r.report_id)
```

Comment: This is looking rather promising. Just at a first glance, it seems to be running much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM reports AS r
JOIN reportvalues AS rv ON rv.report_id = r.report_id
JOIN metrics AS m ON m.metric_id = rv.metric_id
LEFT JOIN exclude_report er ON r.report_id = er.report_id
WHERE er.report_id IS NULL
```

Comment: hmmm, just wondering if that's sufficient. It wouldn't be the other way around....

Comment: Would work but NOT EXISTS is more efficient as it doesn't retrieve the row from exclude_report.

Comment: @Mark Storey-Smith: are you sure NOT EXISTS is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the distinct keyword, which can be heavy. I'd also advise you to add indices on the foreign keys of large tables.

Comment: Dropping the `DISTINCT` doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shold have the followings indexes:

- field `report_id` on table `report`
- field `report_id` on table `reportvalues`
- field `metric_id` on table `reportvalues`
- field `metric_id` on table `metrics`
- field `report_id` on table `exclude_report`